# 'SparkContext' object has no attribute 'textfile'

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I tried loading a file by using following code:

```
textdata = sc.textfile('hdfs://localhost:9000/file.txt')
```

Error message:

> AttributeError: 'SparkContext' object has no attribute 'textfile'

Comment: method name is wrong.. use **textFile** instead of **textfile**.

Comment: On a side note, I guess this happens because Spark is written in Java/Scala and the naming convention for methods is `lowerCamelCase`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is `sc.textFile(...)` with a capital `F`.

You can inspect the API of SparkContext [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext).

Comment: Thanks! for that Daniel :)